# What are the best tools for the beta version of Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

What is the best set of tools to use for developing Silverlight 3 applications while it is in beta?  I want to be able to easily transition into the released version when it comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having good luck with the [Silverlight 3 beta site](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx).

The beta tools for [Visual Studio](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=143571) allgedly work with the Express edition.
I'm finding that you need a combination of [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/blendpreview) and Visual Stuido to really get things done (unlike Flex where everything is in the one IDE).

The [RIA Services](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=144609) look interesting too.

Answer (score 2):

[Expression Blend 3 preview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/blendpreview.aspx) is one you will want to use

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Blend 3 Preview.

For side-by-side development, the VS2010 beta will allow you to target both Silverlight 2.0 and 3.0 without swapping installed bits.